# reading csv that has punctuation on column names using pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

i have a csv file as below only one column(cust_code) with quotation marks and each row also has quotations

```
“CUST_CODE”
“CST001001”
“CST000235”
“CST010231”
“CST010235”
“CST010231”
“CST010235”
“CST010231”
“CST040015”
```

i am tried to read this file in pandas and i'm getting error as

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 0: invalid start byte

also, i tried by passing encoding type as ascii and utf-8
but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `encoding='cp1252'` instead. Make sure to swap out `'Documents\Book1.csv'` with whatever your filepath to the file is below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Documents\Book1.csv', encoding='cp1252')
df

    “CUST_CODE”
0   “CST001001”
1   “CST000235”
2   “CST010231”
3   “CST010235”
4   “CST010231”
5   “CST010235”
6   “CST010231”
7   “CST040015”
```

Here is a wikipedia with more info about that encoding type: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 . A quote from the Wikipedia article:

`"...common result was that all the quotes and apostrophes (produced by "smart quotes" in word-processing software) were replaced with question marks or boxes on non-Windows operating systems, making text difficult to read."`